# Timeframe with IF

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to add conditions in a timeframe.multiplier

I have try this code but the plot line is "Undeclared identifier"

I try to search the solution but i don't find.

```
indicator("My script")
// ————— Converts current chart timeframe into a float minutes value.
f_tfInMinutes() => 
    _tfInMinutes = timeframe.multiplier * (
      timeframe.isseconds ? 1. / 60             :
      timeframe.isminutes ? 1.                  :
      timeframe.isdaily   ? 60. * 24            :
      timeframe.isweekly  ? 60. * 24 * 7        :
      timeframe.ismonthly ? 60. * 24 * 30.4375  : na)


if f_tfInMinutes() == 15
    float my_time = f_tfInMinutes() + 15
else if f_tfInMinutes() == 30
    float my_time = f_tfInMinutes() + 30
else if f_tfInMinutes() == 60
    float my_time = f_tfInMinutes() + 180

plot(my_time)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I have found a part of the solution 

my_time = int(na)

No error but not plot too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the `my_time` variable, and then assign values. Like this:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

float my_time = na

// ————— Converts current chart timeframe into a float minutes value.
f_tfInMinutes() => 
    _tfInMinutes = timeframe.multiplier * (
      timeframe.isseconds ? 1. / 60             :
      timeframe.isminutes ? 1.                  :
      timeframe.isdaily   ? 60. * 24            :
      timeframe.isweekly  ? 60. * 24 * 7        :
      timeframe.ismonthly ? 60. * 24 * 30.4375  : na)


if f_tfInMinutes() == 15
    my_time := f_tfInMinutes() + 15
else if f_tfInMinutes() == 30
    my_time := f_tfInMinutes() + 30
else if f_tfInMinutes() == 60
    my_time := f_tfInMinutes() + 180

plot(my_time)
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  Works and i have understand my error.